# Why does Shichika's sister sit off to the side behind a column?

Tags: katanagatari

In episode 1, between 10 - 15 minutes in to the episode, Shichika, his sister, and Togame are talking in the house.  At some point, the sister moves off to the side and behind a column or curtain.

Why does she do this?

I thought she might be making tea or something, but you never see her do anything.  It also looks like she is facing away from her guest.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is just my speculation from seeing your screenshots, as I don't remember the scene. But it feels to me that it is meant to symbolize that Nanami is not part of the discussion. Sitting far and facing away means she is not supposed to talk and anything she says can be ignored by those actually engaged in the dicussion.

This is understandable because it is Shichika who is head of the family. And moreso that Nanami is a woman. Because this is a culture where women were often not meant to have power and make decissions.